# How to handle procedure hang in the main thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a procedure (let's call it `proc1`) that is called inside another one (`mainproc`) and from time to time the procedure `proc1` hangs or executes for a time not worth waiting. `mainproc` is called inside the main thread. I would like to know what is the best decision in a case like this - is there a way to detect if the procedure won't respond after a certain amount of time without multithreading and if not what is the best way to handle the wait with threads :

```
procedure proc1;
begin
  // statements that can be executed in a few milliseconds or much slower
end;

procedure mainproc;
begin
  // statements part1
  proc1;
  // statements part2
end;
```

Comment: A thread does not know if it is hanging or not. It needs an outside perspective.

Comment: Create a worker thread to do what you must and let another thread (main thread or not) check up on it from time to time. Do consider that if that worker procedure needs to work with things in the main thread (GUI) then you need to place precautions.

Comment: Don't execute long running code in the main thread because it breaks the UI

Comment: It would really help if we knew anything about the code that is actually causing the hang - there could be half a dozen solutions if we knew what the problem actually was.

Answer (score -1):

You need a guard thread monitoring entering and exiting of `proc1`.

For example, the `proc1` sets an autoreset signalling event **A** on entering and sets an autoreset signalling event **B** on exiting; the guard thread is infinitely waiting on the event **A**; when **A** occurs the guard thread starts waiting for the event **B** for a given timeout; if timeout occurs then `proc1` is hanging.

Comment: It's possible that this is the correct solution, but it is also possible that `proc1` simply has a bug that manifests in something like an infinite loop - building a guard thread to kill a fundamentally buggy procedure (which itself would also need to be pushed to a separate thread to be kill-able), rather than just fixing the problem is a really bad idea.  At this point, we don't know enough to suggest a proper solution, imo.

Comment: And then what? You are still stuck in this function blocking the UI thread with no way out.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - why do you think this is a GUI application? IMO the question makes sense in a console app only.

Comment: @user246408 GUI or not, OP states that this is running in the main thread.  If the main thread hangs it's game over - there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @J... - Not true - you can terminate the application from the guard thread.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that this was a GUI app. If not, then my comments are nonsense.

Comment: @user246408 Well, yeah, but that's kind of what I meant when I said "game over".  There's nothing you can do but kill the application.  Not exactly graceful.  If you move the offending procedure to a background thread at least you can call it with a timeout - kill the thread running the procedure if it goes too long but the application can otherwise recover.  Killing the entire application isn't really a sane exception handling technique...

Comment: @J... actually a guard thread may continue running doing some job, for example outputting error messages. On OS level there is very little difference between main and background threads, the difference is more about application design.

Comment: @user246408 It still feels like awful design, at least in general.  Unless `proc1` is the only thing the main thread was responsible for, and even then, one would think that it should at least have opportunity to clean up after such a hang and terminate gracefully - especially if there are other threads in the process that intend to continue running.  Just nuking it when it gets stuck is bound to lead to problems.